# Echo message if no search resultsq

Tags: php, search, echo

The following code echos my search results on to the page. I am trying to echo a message when there are no search results but can't seem to get the message to show.

What is the best way for me to check if there are no results??

Code:

```
    <?php if(isset($search_results)) {foreach($search_results as $result): ?>

<?php  if(empty($search_results)) {echo 'No results';}
    else {
    echo '<div class="search_result"> <b>'.$result['title'].'</b><br />';
   echo '<span class="search_result_url">'.$result['link'].'</span><br />';
   echo $result['text'].'<br /></div>';
    } ?>

    <?php endforeach; } else {echo '<b>Please type what you are looking for into the search bar and press \'enter\'</b>';}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether your $search_results array is empty before the foreach loop

```
 <?php 
if( isset($search_results) ) {
    if( empty($search_results) ) {
        echo 'No results';
    } else {
        foreach($search_results as $result) {
            echo '<div class="search_result"> <b>'.$result['title'].'</b><br />';
            echo '<span class="search_result_url">'.$result['link'].'</span><br />';
            echo $result['text'].'<br /></div>';
         }
    } 
} else {
    echo '<b>Please type what you are looking for into the search bar and press \'enter\'</b>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your script cannot possibly work, since the foreach loop is cast as soon as $search_results is NOT empty, thus if(empty($search_results)) {echo 'No results';} is never true.

try if(empty($result)) {echo 'No results';}

or if($result!='$empty') {echo 'No results';} ($empty depending on what 'empty' means)

Comment: [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is a standard PHP function.

Comment: yes, but the poster did not specify in what sense the result is 'empty'. it could also include html tags like "<div> </div>". in those circumstances, empty() would return FALSE. but i guess i should clarify that more in my answer..